# Blob upload unauthorized Server failed to authenticate the request exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I used this code a week ago and everything was fine. My colleagues are still using the exact same code and they have no problem at all.

```
StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey heronStorage = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("heron", "someKey");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient("someUrl", heronStorage);
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containerName");
container.CreateIfNotExist();
container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
```

This code throws:`"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."` at `container.CreateIfNotExist();` line.

I copied their code and it's still the same. I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your system clock is properly synchronized, wrong time zone and improper synchronization causes hashes to fail. As servers use time as part of synchronization to validate requests.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem.

Comment: should our system time matches the UTC time ? what you mean by synchronization.

Comment: In Windows server, there is option to synchronize time with time servers, they are all synchronized with utc, if your timezone is correct, your server will be upto date with time. Computer clocks aren't perfect, they need to be set correctly and there is automatic service for that.

Comment: My system time is Tue, 14 Jul 2015 22:24:47 (Indian standard time) but  the UTC time i'm getting in c# is "Tue, 14 Jul 2015 16:45:47 GMT". Using windows azure East US. Should i need to make any changes, i'm getting signature not matched exception.