# Mstest command failing Intermittently when calling from powershell

Tags: powershell, mstest, azure-devops

```
function LoginNormal
{
    $MSTestCall = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio    14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
    $MSTestArguments = @('/testsettings:C:\PerformanceTests\Local.testsettings')
    $file="C:\LoadTestsQA\Login_Normal.loadtest"
    $MSTestArguments += "/TestContainer:" + $file
    & $MSTestCall $MSTestArguments
}
function LoginPeak
{
    $MSTestCall = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
    $MSTestArguments = @('/testsettings:C:\PerformanceTests\Local.testsettings')
    $file="C:\LoadTestsQA\Login_Peak.loadtest"
    $MSTestArguments += "/TestContainer:" + $file
    & $MSTestCall $MSTestArguments
}
LoginNormal
LoginPeak
```

This powershell script executes Visual studio online load test with the help of MSTest using powershell. 
Even though this script gives me the desired output , some times any one of the function will get failed and out put is like following :

> Starting execution...
>   Connecting to https://mytestsite.visualstudio.com
>   Initializing
>   One or more errors occurred.
>   Failed
>
> Final Test Results:
>   Results               Top Level Tests
>   -------               ---------------
>   Not Executed          c:\performancetests\loadtestsqa\login_normal.loadtest
>   0/1 test(s) Passed, 1 Not Executed

Comment: Is that all the (error) output you get?

Comment: @Jocke When  I open the result file .trx  of the non executed load test in visual studio I am getting following error message:
Not Executed LoadTest_Peak  Warning: only a part of test result was loaded because test type implementation is not available.

Comment: How often do you see this error? Does it still occur if you run it again immediately?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Yes , Actually I have 4 load tests and I need to run each of them twice . So I have created a powershell script and added 4 functions for each of the tests and I will call the function twice like this:
LoginNormal LoginPeak TestNormal TestPeak LoginNormal LoginPeak TestNormal TestPeak 
If the first 3 functions successfully creates the load test in VSO then sometimes the 4th one might get failed. If I try to run the failed test again separately then it might create the load test in VSO.

Comment: Exception details in .trx file when opened in notepad:
<Exception>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---&gt; Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.Client.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:8d0283a9-0001-003d-2994-h09b6d000000
Time:2016-06-07T08:11:36.8072816Z

Comment: That looks like a Azure issue. How is vs-team-services hosted for you?

Comment: @Jocke I am using URL-based load test with Visual Studio Team Service

Comment: @Aathira Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874847/blob-upload-unauthorized-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-exception

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT The System clock is properly synchronized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I’ve managed to find a solution for this. As this one fails to create the load test in visual studio team service intermittently I will call the same function again until it creates the load test.

```
function LoginNormal
    {
    $MSTestCall = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
    $MSTestArguments = @('/testsettings:C:\PerformanceTests\Local.testsettings')
    $file="C:\LoadTestsQA\Login_Normal.loadtest"
    $MSTestArguments += "/TestContainer:" + $file
    Trap {Continue} Stop-Transcript | out-null
    Start-Transcript -path C:\test\s.txt -append
    & $MSTestCall $MSTestArguments
    Stop-Transcript
    $c=Select-String -Path C:\test\s.txt -SimpleMatch "Test Run Failed."
 checkStringLoginNormal($c)
}
function checkStringLoginNormal($arg1)
{
    if(-Not $arg1)
    {
        Start-Sleep -s 60
        Remove-Item C:\test\s.txt
        LoginPeak
    }
else
    {
    Start-Sleep -s 60
    Remove-Item C:\test\s.txt
    #calls the LoginNormal function until the text file contains the text "Test Run Failed."
     LoginNormal 
    }
}
LoginNormal
```